# What is the need for firewall to be in "stealth mode"?

Tags: network, attacks, firewalls, attack-prevention, network-scanners

There is a firewall deployment case called "[transparent mode](https://www.fortinet.com/resources/cyberglossary/transparent-firewall)", when the firewall does its job without routing and having IPv4 addresses, i.e. it is invisible.

"Stealth mode" is mentioned as one of the advantages:

> Because transparent firewalls do not have an IP address within the
> network, they are more stealthy and undetectable by attackers. This
> provides a major security advantage because it means the network is
> less susceptible to hacker attacks that use network probes or
> denial-of-service (DoS) attacks.

Why is the network less susceptible to attack? How does this help with DoS?
It seems that this mode can help to avoid DoS of the firewall itself, but not DoS on the network.

How undetectable firewall helps to defend the network?

Sorry if an answer is obvious.

My related post: [What are the reasons to use a firewall in transparent mode?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1088977/what-are-the-reasons-to-use-a-firewall-in-transparent-mode)

Comment: I agree that Fortinet's wording is confusing there.

Comment: Useful link: https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/what-is-stealth-mode/170505790029839/

Answer (score 2):

If the attacker knows the firewall model, it's easier to find exploits to it and bypass it. If the version is known, the job is even easier. On a stealth firewall, the attacker may not even suspect there's a firewall, so it's harder for him to find a way to bypass it.

If the firewall has a routable IP address, an attacker can flood the firewall address with traffic, leading to resource exhaustion, and denying access to everyone depending on the firewall. If the firewall sits between the internal network and the internet, the attacker can disable the firewall and the internal network cannot access the internet anymore.

Comment: It should be mentioned that some firewalls have a "fail open" mode, meaning that if the firewall fails for any reason, it will let all traffic through.

Comment: @MechMK1 Ugh.  That seems like a vector for attack.

Comment: @JimmyJames "fail closed", meaning that if the firewall fails, no traffic gets through, is also a vector for attack.

Comment: @MechMK1 Good point.  I guess it depends on what you are more worried about.  In my work, we'd much rather do nothing than do the wrong thing.